# intellij plugin development add marker to specific line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm currently writing an Intellij-Plugin, which performs some static analyses to find mathematical formulas. (see image)

[image]

My result references to a specific line (see yellow mark). Currently I'm opening a custom JFrame to show the detected formula.

In the next version of this plugin i want to add a marker on the red marked position next to the line number. (line a breakpoint)
A click on this marker should open a small/lightweight UI where i can render my formula (=JComponent) as shown in the picture below.

[image]

What intellij class should i look at?

Comment: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development would be a better place for IntelliJ IDEA plug-in development questions.

Answer (score 2):

LineMarkerProvider is what you are looking for.

Also there is a 
[related tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/line_marker_provider.html).

Comment: But how do i get the right PSI Element for this line?

Comment: I assumed that you know which PSI elements you want to equip with line marks. If not I recommend to install PsiViewer plugin and view PSI structure of code areas you are interested in. It seems that you should search for PsiExpression or one of it descending classes.

Comment: Ok :-/ well, i thought i could just mark the line by it's its offset (=line number).